# How create a file csv after zip file that csv and save file zip at server

Tags: php

I want to create a file csv after zip this file csv and save file zip at server.
I code as:

```
 foreach($list as $item)
        { 
            $csv .= join("\t", $item)."\r\n"; 
        }  

        $csv = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($csv,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8");

        header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
        header("Content-disposition: csv; filename=CSV_".date("YmdHis").".csv; size=".strlen($csv));

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name ="CSV_".$dateTimeNow.".zip"; // Zip name
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
        {                         
              $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }
        $zip->addFile($csv);
        $zip->close();
```

file csv has created ok, but zip file and save file still not sucesssfull.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is not successful because `$zip->addFile` is expecting a file but `chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($csv,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8")` was returned

Here is the solution

```
$csv = "ABC" ; // Define CSV to avoid notice error 
$csv = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($csv,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8");

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-disposition: csv; filename=CSV_".date("YmdHis").".csv; size=".strlen($csv));

$file_name =  "abc.csv";
file_put_contents($file_name, $csv); // dump csv to temp file 

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "CSV.zip" ; // Zip name
touch($zip_name);

if ($zip->open($zip_name) === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile($file_name); // add the temp file to zip
    $zip->close();
} else {
     $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

unlink($file_name); // remove temp csv
```

Comment: file_put_contents($file_name, $csv); command doesn't create temp file. It show download file abc.csv.html

Comment: @mum i don't know where you got `.html` at the end of your file ....... i ran the code and it works perfectly fine

Comment: I code:  $filename='CSV_123.csv";
            file_put_contents($file_name, $csv); but don't save file ,It's show dialog save file CSV_123.csv.

Comment: `$filename` is different from `$file_name` ??? am not sure i can help you further if you continue to change things this way

Comment: I'm sorry , i had changed to   $filename='CSV_123.csv";
            file_put_contents($filename, $csv); // Create temp file  but ,It's still show dialog save file CSV_123.csv

Comment: @ Baba, it's save ok and zip ok, but it's still show dialog save file CSV_123.csv